# How to remove Kotlin from React native project

Tags: react-native, kotlin, android-studio, create-react-native-app

I worked in Flutter, and now I switch to React Native, but when I create a new React Native project, kotlinversion and ndkversion are added automatically to the *build.gradle* file in the project.

How do I stop the Kotlin version from being added to my React Native project?

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5xwE.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [do not post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). [edit] your question to **add that text as well-formatted text** in a code block.

Comment: Can be a cache/system leftover. If you really run the final APP on IDE-wrapper and not on the JVM like maybe before it should work. For me IntelliJ sometimes brings up such behavior. Invalidate cache. 
PS: Any maybe settings are wrong not completly adapted since kotlin is android default on flutter

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed issue.** It was not an issue or problem, but it was a problem with the React Native version. Version 0.73 of React Native adds Kotlin and the NDK version by default. so down the version of react native using:

npx react-native init ProjectName --version X.XX.X